# How to find history of test plans created in MTM 2010?

Tags: testing, microsoft-test-manager

Is there any way to find who added/deleted test cases in test plans in Microsoft Test Manager?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way since *Test Plan* and *Test Suites* are not *TFS Work Items* in *MTM 2010*, that means they don't have any history.

The good news is that they became *Work Items* in [TFS 2013 Update 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/05/23/test-plan-and-test-suite-customization-with-tfs2013-update3.aspx) The part "**History/Auditing for changes to Test Plan and Test Suite**" is exactly what you are asking for.